# call rest api using Ajax by calling function

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, user-interface

I have to call the rest API and get the response currently I am doing like this and its perfectly working fine , But I need to call this via the function and need to pass the two params which will be used in the URL and need to return the response from that function, so that I can use it the response in other classes.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "BaseURL"+param1+"/" + param2
}).then(function (data) {
  if (data.test== null)
    self.prop1(data.test);
  if (data.test2 !== null)
    self.prop2(data.test2);
  if (data.test3 !== null)
    self.prop3(data.test3)
});
```

Can u please suggest some way to do this , please let me know if you need any information from my side.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you build the URL outside of the function:

```
// Define URL variable 
var BaseURL = 'www.baseurl.com';
var param1 = '<param1>';
var param2 = '<param2>';
var URL = `${BaseURL}${param1}/${param2}`

function AJAXPost(RequestType, formData, URL){
    $.ajax({
      url: URL
      type: RequestType,
      data: formData
      //Test success / error
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function with both parameters and a third parameter as tyhe callback, to return the data

```
function request(param1, param2, callback) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "BaseURL"+param1+"/" + param2
  }).then(function(data) {
    callback(data);
  });
}
```

Or with async

```
const req = async (param1, param2) => {
  try {
    let data = await $.ajax({url: `BaseURL${param1}/${param2}`});
    return data;
  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
}
```

Comment: in the first approach to call the above function from the other script file
and get the response